# Retrieving data from a firebase collection having same value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am new to Android and would appreciate some kind insights into this issue. I am trying to fetch data from the firebase based on "Type" key as shown in the image below.
The idea is to get data having the same "Type", **then display the value of "Type" as a heading and show the remaining data in recycler/listview.**

[image: Sample data from Firebase]

Currently, I am at the stage where I can display data in the RecyclerView according to Restaurant Id, but I am unable to proceed further with the logic of how to address the problem stated above. My code to show data based on restaurant id:

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Category");

FirebaseRecyclerOptions<CategoryModel> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<CategoryModel>()
                .setQuery(databaseReference.orderByChild("RestaurantID").equalTo(r_id), CategoryModel.class)
                .build();

firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<CategoryModel, RestaurantDetailsViewHolder>(options) {

@NonNull
@Override
public RestaurantDetailsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
hideLoading();
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.restaurant_details_view, parent, false);
    RestaurantDetailsViewHolder viewHolder = new RestaurantDetailsViewHolder (v);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RestaurantDetailsViewHolder holder,
                                            int position, @NonNull CategoryModel model) {
    holder.category.setText(model.getType());
    holder.item_name.setText(model.getItemName());
    holder.item_ingredients.setText(model.getIngredients());
    holder.item_price.setText("" + model.getPrice());
    holder.setItemImage(model.getImage());
    }
};
recyclerViewDetails.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
```

Please enlighten with your suggestions. Thank you

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: @Sairaj Sawant I haven't tried any code mainly because I dont know the logic to implement such design. That is why I am asking the question  But i'll edit my question with the last stage of code before I got stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a simple workaround. Basically, I just changed my database design to have "Type" as a separate collection in firebase and supplying the Restaurant Id to "Type", then "Type" id to respective Category collection as shown in the image.

[image]

This way I can access items related to each category and display in another activity.